# pros and cons for multi-site drupal setup

Tags: drupal

What would be pros and cons for multi-site drupal setup with over 10gb entries to either use "domains module"  vs using different installations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain module is good, if you want to share users and content among the sites, as it allow you to manage on which site the content should be available.

If you want to make a normal multi-site setup, with different databases (no shared content/users) you should make different installations (which can use the same drupal core and contrib modules)